# Prolog PostFix Issue

Tags: prolog, append, prefix, suffix

I'm having trouble solving this prolog problem. Define a postfix predicate so that postfix(X,Y) says that X is a list that is a postfix of Y. That is, each element of X is equal to (unifies with) the corresponding element of Y, but Y may contain additional elements before that.

IN:

```
postfix(X,[1,2,3]).
```

OUT:

```
[]; [3]; [2,3]; [1,2,3];
```

I tried

```
postFix(X,[]). 
postFix(X,Y) :- append(,X,Y), [H|T] is Y, postfix(,X,T).
```

Thanks!

Comment: What dit you try yourself so far? Add some examples input/ouput.

Comment: I have tried using append function like append(_,X,Y).
So the user can pass postfix(X,[1,2,3]) then they should get []; [3]; [2,3]; [1,2,3];.

Comment: I have tried 
postFix(X,[]).
postFix(X,Y) :-
  append(_,X,Y),
  [H|T] is Y,
  postfix(_,X,T).

Comment: Very good, where did you get? What's not working. Show us what you got and where you got stuck in your question.

Comment: I do not know how exactly to tackle this problem. But I did commented what i did so far. I have Final Exam tomorrow, and i need to learn this. So it will really helpful if someone can explain this step by step using Append function Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually pretty close. It's a lot simpeler
So postfix means appending anything before `X`, that is resulting in `Y`

This is what [append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) does: `append(prefix,postfix,list)`

```
postfix(X,Y) :- append(_,X,Y).
```

Example:

```
- postfix(X,[1,2,3]).
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
X = [2, 3] ;
X = [3] ;
X = [] ;
false.
```

If you want this as a list

```
postfixList(X,Y) :- findall(P,append(_,P,Y),X);
```

Comment: I tried that But it only gives me [1,2,3]. I want to see all possible combination. Like [], [3], [2,3], [1,2,3].

Comment: How did you check this? I tested it with the expected results.

Comment: Ohh i was trying to hit enter. But Now i Know I just needed to press ';'. Got it thank you.

Comment: you're not alone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463248/why-does-swi-prolog-only-give-me-the-first-answer/34463275