# Why does SWI-Prolog only give me the first answer?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'm new to Prolog. I'm just trying simple examples to learn. I have this `.pl` file with these lines:

```
parent(pam,bob).
parent(tom,bob).
parent(tom,lio).
parent(bob,ann).
parent(bob,pat).
parent(pat,jim).
```

After consulting and testing, it only shows the first answer. For example:

```
5 ?- parent(X,Y).
X = pam,
Y = bob .
```

Isn't it supposed to give all the combinations that satisfy the relation `parent`?

Do anyone have idea what the problem is?

Comment: don't hit enter after your first results shows, use spacebar instead

Comment: perfect. Thanx for the help.

Comment: I've added this as an answer since I've got the feeling you are not the only one running into this.

Answer (score 16):

don't hit enter after your first results shows, use spacebar instead

- `[Enter]` stops execution even if the backtracking is not completed yet
- `[Spacebar]` or `[;]` continues with backtracking from your last result to the next result or `false` if there are no other results left.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference between space and enter does for future readers, too?

Comment: I thought that was already clear, but if not, I hope this will do. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't say 'false' when no answers left. Display each result for every ';' and then goes to ?-.  I'm trying on SWI-Prolog 8.2.4.