# Uninstantiated variable at end of list in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

I wrote a program to sort numbers from symbols, and it works, but gives me a memory address at the end of the list that it didn't run through last. Why is that so?

```
separate([],[],[]).
separate([X],X,_):-number(X).
separate([X],_,X).
separate([X|Y],[X|Z],S):-number(X),separate(Y,Z,S).
separate([X|Y],Z,[X|S]):-separate(Y,Z,S).
```

When consulting with `?- separate([3,a,b,4,5,c],X,Y).`

I get:

```
X = [3, 4, 5|_G2592],
Y = [a, b, c] .
```

Comment: Instead of pressing `Enter` after seeing the answer, what happens if you press the space bar. See: [Why does SWI-Prolog only give me the first answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34463248/1243762)

Comment: It also helps when first learning Prolog not to use variables like `X` and `Y` but more meaningful names such as `Digit`, `Letter`, `Digits`, `Letters`, `Rest`. Once you understand what is happening then you can revert back to `X` and `Y`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you **leave your list tails open**:

```
separate([X],X,_):-number(X).
separate([X],_,X).
```

The thing is: you actually do not need to write these statements, you could have omitted them:

```
separate([],[],[]).
separate([X|Y],[X|Z],S):-number(X),separate(Y,Z,S).
separate([X|Y],Z,[X|S]):-separate(Y,Z,S).
```

This would have worked **but it would return multiple results**, and **except the first, all the remaining are wrong**. You should solve this by adding a guard to the last clause:

```
separate([],[],[]).
separate([X|Y],[X|Z],S):-number(X),separate(Y,Z,S).
separate([X|Y],Z,[X|S]):-\+ number(X),separate(Y,Z,S).
```

Where `\+` acts like a "not" in the sense that `\+ number(X)` will succeed if Prolog cannot match `number(X)`.

A final note is that what you see is not really a memory address: it is simply an uninstantiated variable, although that is of course a minor remark.

Comment: Wasn't sure if it's a memory address or not, but it was the closest I thought it was, thanks for clearing that up too. The \+ is unknown to me and was never mentioned in our script.

Comment: @Streamline: ah `\+` acts like a "not" (although it is dangerous to say that). It is a not in the sense that if Prolog fails to match `number(a)` for instance, `\+ number(a)` will succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I propose

```
separate([],[],[]).

separate([H | T], [H | Tn], Ls) :-
  number(H),
  separate(T, Tn, Ls).

separate([H | T], Ln, [H | Ts]) :-
  \+ number(H),
  separate(T, Ln, Ts).
```

If you have a terminal clause as `separate([],[],[])` and a couple of ordinary clauses as `separate([X|Y],[X|Z],S)` and `separate([X|Y],Z,[X|S])`, you don't need semi-terminal clauses as `separate([X],X,_)` and `separate([X],_,X)` and they (with the undefined value `_`) avoid the unification of one of the lists and you get the "memory address" (the identifier of a not-unified variable).

And if you have a clause with `number(X)`, the other (alternative) clause need the "not-number" check (that is `\+ number(X)`) otherwise both clauses are true with numbers and you multiply solutions, with numbers in the list of not numbers.